# How to set background-image 100% with floats?

Tags: html, css

I`ve tried to set the left-right borders as a background-image with repeat-y=100%, but it didn`t work. It works fine when I set the outer box to strict height like 100px, but I need it to be 100% either.
The CSS:

```
      .border_left {
    background:url('borderLeft.png') top left repeat-y;
    height:100%;
    width:14px;        
    float:left;
  }
  .border_right {
    background:url('borderRight.png') top right repeat-y;
    height:100%;
    width:14px;        
    float:left;
  }
  .center_box {
     height:100%;
     float:left;
  }
```

HTML:

```
  <div>
   <div class="border_left"></div>
   <div class="center_box">
     sdvfdsfvdfs
     vsdfvdsfv<br/>
     sdfvdfvdsfvd
     sdfvdsfvdsfv<br/>
     sdfv<br/>
     sdfvvsdfvdfs<br/>
     sdfvdfs<br/>
   </div>
   <div class="border_right"></div>
   <div style="clear:both;"></div>
 </div>
```

As U can see everything is simple, but do not work at all, I've also tried to set min-height:100px; - this just solves the problem only stretching it by 100px.
PS In shorthend description - I need the 2 borders repeat-y=100% within the inner content.
Sorry for my English =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your "float" style into an absolute position style:

```
.border_left {
    background: url('borderLeft.png') top left repeat-y;
    height: 100%;
    width: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
}

.border_right {
    background: url('borderRight.png') top right repeat-y;
    height: 100%;
    width: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: It works improperly for me, because this change stretches boxes to 100% of all the body and lay down on each other, so I see just the one on the left side and from "head to foot". Sorry I'd found the mistake and it is set to left and right.

Comment: So outer div should be 100% width, but height flexible?add 'position: relative;' to the outer div and it should work fine.
- Or I didn't get the problem right.

Comment: Thank U very much pal, U`ve saved me a lot of time - I'm glad that there is a professionals like U in the world, without any lyrics - just the right solution.

Comment: That's so nice to hear :) I joined stackoverflow 2 days ago and I'm happy I can help other people. - Made my day!
But just some more background information on that: 
'position: absolute' - " The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element".
Because the default position in css is 'static', the .border_left was oriented on body. By giving the outer div an 'position: relative', it is orienting on the outer div now (because it's the first NOT static (anymore) ancestor element.)

Answer (score 0):

set the height for outer containet to 100%

Let me know if that help.

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunatelly it doesn`t help - I've tried this before and did it again - no issue.

Comment: You are also missing display:block on the divs with background

Comment: On top of everything to fix the not displayed div with css background,  you need to have some content in div.  Just add space as & nbsp;